# React 16 upgrade - select lists return Object Object

Tags: reactjs, react-16

I've got an app I'm upgrading from `React 15` to `React 16`

In some instances of mapping and using a select list which were working in `React 15` are now not working - I'm finding that the select list are returning a list of `[object, Object]`

Here's my code

```
  let carTypes = ["ford", "volvo", "tesla", "BMW"];

  return (
        <div>
          <select>
            {carTypes.map((carType, key) => {
              return (
                <option
                  key={key}
                >
                  <span>{carType}</span>
                </option>)
            })}
          </select>

          <ul>
            {carTypes.map((carType, key) => {
              return (
                <li
                  key={key}
                >
                  <span>{carType}</span>
                </li>)
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
    )
```

So in the above code the select list will render in the browser a select list with 4 options - all of them read `[object, Object]`

The below unordered list returns the 4 items and renders them correctly in the browser displaying the 4 car types

My guess was that select lists mark up has changed in `React 16` but I've found no documentation of that

If anyone can point me in the right direction / advice or show me some documentation that would be great!

Comment: change `carType.map((filingType, key)` to `carTypes.map((filingType, key)`

Comment: You just misspelled . You did put carType wich is an array instead of filingType

Comment: And also carType doesn't exist out of carTypes map function

Comment: Sorry some typos @A.R.SEIF - all fixed now so hopefully clearer

Comment: Sorry some typos @DarthJS - all fixed now so hopefully clearer

Answer (score 1):

i wrote this code .

```
let carTypes = ["ford", "volvo", "tesla", "BMW"];

  return (
    <div>
      <select>
        {carTypes.map((carType, key) => {
          return <option key={key}>{carType}</option>;
        })}
      </select>

      <ul>
        {carTypes.map((carType, key) => {
          return (
            <li key={key}>
              <span>{carType}</span>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

**Work Demo**

[image: CodeSandbox]

Answer (score 0):

Remove span tag from option tag

```
let carTypes = ["ford", "volvo", "tesla", "BMW"];

    return (
        <div>
            <select>
                {carTypes.map((carType,key) => {
                    return (
                        <option
                           key={key}
                        >
                            {carType}
                        </option>)
                })}
            </select>

            <ul>
                {carTypes.map((carType, key) => {
                    return (
                        <li
                            key={key}
                        >
                            <span>{carType}</span>
                        </li>)
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
```